# How to sort NSTableView with custom class data

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I am using cell-based tableview to store custom class data, for example

```
class Person {
    var name:String = ""
    var age: Int = 0
}
```

And then use a NSMUtableArray to collect person1, person2 ... datas, call it dataArray.

Present Person name on column1 and age on column2, works fine and editable.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {
    if tableColumn?.identifier == "Name"
    {
        return (self.dataArray[row] as! Person).name
    }
    else if tableColumn?.identifier == "Age"
    {
        return (self.dataArray[row] as! Person).age
    }

}
```

How can I sort each column with respected sortDescriptor?

I follow that [fefernce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095737/sorting-nstableview) but **"sortDescriptorWithKey:tableColumn.identifier"** always fail in my code, it can be passed if set the tableColumn.identifier to **"self"**, it also confused me.

Below are my other code fragments.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, sortDescriptorsDidChange oldDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor]) {
    let newDescriptors = tableView.sortDescriptors
    dataArray.sort(using: newDescriptors)
    tableView.reloadData()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    // Sort
    for tableColumn in tableView.tableColumns {
        let sortDescrptor = NSSortDescriptor.init(key: tableColumn.identifier, ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.caseInsensitiveCompare))
        tableColumn.sortDescriptorPrototype = sortDescrptor
    }

}
```

Comment: `caseInsensitiveCompare` won't work with integers. Why don't you set the sort keys in the XIB?

Comment: Should I use the dictionary type for storing the data?

Comment: No, a custom class is ok.

Comment: I have tried using sort descriptor in xib, but the compiler says that it's not key-value type.

Comment: How did you set the sort descriptor in the XIB?

Comment: For column 1, set the sort key to "name" and selector to "compare:".

Comment: Sounds ok. What is the exact error from the XIB compiler?

Comment: It shows: **Unrecognized selector -[project.PersonData valueForKeyPath:]**, I think I should write the selector compare: in that class, right?

Comment: This sounds like a corrupted XIB, a bug in the XIB compiler or a Swift problem.